# Оптимальный вариант выбора Java report engine

Tags: java

Передо мной стоит вопрос выбора движка для создания отчетов. В голову сразу приходит мысль о JasperReports, благо лицензия GNU LGPL и есть визуальный дизайнер iReports.

Есть ли что-нибудь более функциональное, более "продвинутое"?

Comment: самое простое решение не всегда самое худшее :)

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли что-нибудь более функциональное, более "продвинутое"?

Очень маловероятно. В свое время искал. Есть какие-то мутные коммерческие решения типа Windward Reports, но они все равно не дотягивают до джаспера. Сам мечтаю о порте FastReport на Java.

Answer (score 1):

Самых популярных и "развитых" бесплатных генераторов отчётов под java, пожалуй, два: JasperReports и BIRT.
Ниже приведено краткое сравнение JasperReports Server и BIRT (некоторые пункты, возможно, будут несколько субъективными).

**BIRT**

Плюсы:

- удобный графический интерфейс, относительная простота использования.

Минусы:

- сложность построения отчётов в текстовом формате (.txt) и xml-формате, по умолчанию такой возможности нет.

**JasperReports Server**

Плюсы:

- возможность построения отчётов в текстовом формате (.txt).

Минусы:

- невозможно просмотреть историю запуска заданий по построению отчётов
- в принципе не очень удобный планировщик запуска отчётов
- также по умолчанию нет возможности построения отчёта в xml-формате
- по умолчанию нет поддержки русского языка в интерфейсе - нужно добавлять
  файлы с переводом на русский язык
- меньшее количество поддерживаемых
  источников данных, есть трудности с кодировкой (с выводом отчётов,
  содержащих русский язык).

Answer (score 0):

Из качественных бесплатных генераторов для Java встречается [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/): Eclipse Public License. Но что лучше Jasper или BIRT - это еще большой вопрос.